# Frechet differentiability of superposition operators $F\colon H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded and Lipschitz domain and $F$ be the superposition/Nemytskii operator defined for functions $u\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ via
$$F(u)(x) = f(u(x))$$ where $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$ with bounded derivative. I'm looking for results regarding the Frechet differentiability of $F\colon H^{1}(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$.

I think the above hypotheses on $f$ are enough but I can't find a proof to cite anywhere. Does anyone know a reference? Also, I'm interested in cases replacing $H^1$ with a fractional Sobolev space, if anyone knows of a suitable reference.

All books I've seen thus far deal with mappings between $L^p$ spaces or between Sobolev spaces with no mixing.

Comment: You should look for the corresponding results for $F:L^p\to L^2$ where $H^1\hookrightarrow L^p$

Comment: This should give a pretty large class of functions. The case $f=\exp$ is not covered but leads to a nice map $F:H^1\to L^q$ for $d=2$ by a result of Moser.